# insertion/selection sort in one line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, list-comprehension

What's the best way to write insertion/selection sort in python may be using list comprehensions?
I know this would work
selection :

```
def selection(l):
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
            if l[min_idx] > l[j]:
                min_idx = j
        
        l[i],l[min_idx] = l[min_idx],l[i]

l = [5,1,2,3,4]
selection(l)
```

Pythonic way?

Comment: @superbrain Okay, but is there any optimized or pythonic way to do this?

Comment: @superbrain Unless the list is guaranteed to have 32 or fewer elements >> suppose the input is same as provided in the question, then what would be the approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to shorten min element search:

```
def selection(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
        min_idx = l.index(min(l[i:]), i)
        l[i], l[min_idx] = l[min_idx], l[I]
```

Or alternative variant with constant extra space (thanks to @kaya3):

```
def selection(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
        min_idx = min(range(i, len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)
        l[i], l[min_idx] = l[min_idx], l[i]
```

Or one-line solution (non-optimal - it will probably use some extra space + pop operation is heavy):

```
l = [l.pop(l.index(min(l))) for _ in range(len(l))]
```

Comment: Can you do it with only constant extra space? (Like normal selection sort does.)

Comment: Added example without extra space

Comment: Instead of using `min` to find the minimum value and then `index` to search for it again, `min(range(i, len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)` does it with one search (and avoids the need for slicing or itertools).

Comment: @kaya3 That's char-for-char the exact solution I wanted them to find :-)

Comment: Nice solution, I'll fix the answer

Comment: Hmm, that oneliner isn't bad. Why do you call it non-optimal?

Comment: it use extra space

Comment: not sure how much extra space - it will erase elements while constructing list so may be not so much. need to benchmark